# How to make LEFT JOIN query using sqlx?

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb, sqlx

I'd like to get results from `joke` table where jokes are upvoated in 
 `jokevote` table.

Here is the query:

```
var jokes []model.Joke
err := shared.Dbmap.Select(&jokes, "    SELECT  *
    FROM  joke
    LEFT JOIN  jokevote
    WHERE  joke.user_id=?
      AND  jokevote.user_id=?
      AND  jokevote.vote=1
```

", userId, userId)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("%v \n", err)
    }

But I get this error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'WHERE joke.user_id=? AND jokevote.user_id=? AND
>   jokevote.vote=1' at line 1

I have also tried:

```
err := shared.Dbmap.Select(&jokes, "    SELECT  *
    FROM  joke
    LEFT JOIN  jokevote
    WHERE  joke.user_id=jokevote.user_id
      AND  jokevote.vote=?
```

", 1)

And got the same error.
I looked at [the docs](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) and could not find any example of such joins. 
So wondering how can I fix it.

Comment: This error not related to `sqlx` or `go`. You have SQL syntax error. Execute your SQL query in your DB editor and fix your query. Then use that query in your Go code.

Comment: When using `LEFT JOIN`, you must have an `ON` clause; otherwise the `LEFT` is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples would me in the mariadb docs. What you are missing is the `on` clause that tells mariadb how to join the 2 tables. You cannot use the old-school join syntax with `left join` putting the join criteria into the `where` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM joke
LEFT JOIN jokevote ON joke.user_id=jokevote.user_id
WHERE jokevote.vote=?
```

Comment: Good tip. However I still get this error at runtime:  `missing destination name joke_id`. Any ideas why this occurs?

Comment: No idea, that's not an sql error message. It seems unrelated to the question you have just asked. If you have another question, pls ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Sql query should be like:

```
"SELECT * FROM joke LEFT JOIN jokevote ON joke.user_id=jokevote.user_id WHERE  jokevote.vote=?"
```